# Creating a new column based on multiple condition like unique count & sum

Tags: r, sum, dplyr

```
name <- c("a","a","a","b","b","a","a") 
itr <- c(1,1,2,1,1,3,3) 
var_bin <- c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1) 
sum_var_bin_exp_col <- c(2,2,2,1,1,2,2)
df <- data.frame(name,itr,var_bin,sum_var_bin_exp_col)
```

I want to create a column (`sum_var_bin_exp_col`) and it is based on values given in col `var_bin` & `group_by` `name` and `itr` columns.
`sum_var_bin_exp_col` is basically sum of `var_bin` col that is binary.

There are `itr` 1 , `itr` 2 and `itr` 3 for `name` "a" and `var_bin` is 1 , 0, 1 respectively for `name` 1.

So, total sum is 2... I am counting only once of repeated values.

Comment: So you want to create a new column based on `var_bin` column that it will be sum and it will be grouped  by columns `name` and `itr`?

Comment: yes and also dependent on other columns

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the desired result you can use `dplyr` to achieve it.

```
library(dplyr)

df_res <- df %>% 
   group_by(name, itr) %>% 
   mutate(sum_var_bin_exp = sum(var_bin)

df_res

## A tibble: 7 x 5
## Groups:   name, itr [4]
#  name    itr var_bin sum_var_bin_exp_col sum_var_bin_exp
#  <fct> <dbl>   <dbl>               <dbl>           <dbl>
#1 a      1.00    1.00                2.00            2.00
#2 a      1.00    1.00                2.00            2.00
#3 a      2.00    0                   2.00            0   
#4 b      1.00    1.00                1.00            2.00
#5 b      1.00    1.00                1.00            2.00
#6 a      3.00    1.00                2.00            2.00
#7 a      3.00    1.00                2.00            2.00
```

Comment: If it is to create a new column, use `mutate` instead of `summarize`

Comment: @akrun My mistake. Just changed my answer. Thanks

Comment: it should not be 0 in sum_var_bin_exp .....it should be 2 only.....for name "b" ...it should show only 1 because name b has only itr1 ...it should be counted only once